# How to create a camel route that references a specific Java method?

Tags: java, apache-camel, dsl

I want to write a Camel route that reads all xml files in a specific directory, then calls a process Java method of a class that implements Processor to do something and print the result to screen.

For example the Java class is named ScriptProcessor, and it has a process method:

```
public class ScriptProcessor implements Processor{

    final Script script ;


    public ScriptProcessor(Script script){
        this.script = script;
    }


    @Override
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
       //do something ...

    }

}
```

So, currently I have a camel context with a route like this:

```
   <camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
      <route>
        <from uri="file:?noop=true"/>
        <to uri="mock:result"/>
      </route>
    </camelContext>
```

I suppose that all xml files are in the same directory of the file with the Camel context definition ("from" tag), and I use mock element to specify the destination of route.
I don't know how call the process method of the ScriptProcessor class inwards that Camel route. It's necessary a "process" tag or something similar?
Can someone help me?

Comment: Check out the document on [processor](http://camel.apache.org/processor.html). If you want a little more flexibility look at [bean binding](http://camel.apache.org/bean-binding.html).

Comment: @Ralf Thank you for the answer. Yes I read the documentation about processor and bean binding. But my problem now is to define the route in a XML file and not with Java DSL notation. Following the definition in java about the use of bean, I inserted a bean element into route definition in the XML file,  but I can't to resolve errors.

Comment: Could you please update your question with your route definition and the error you are getting? In general there is a tag of the same name in the Spring DSL for a method in the Java DSL. So if there is a method `process(..)` then there is a tag `<process>` that does the same job. It greatly helps to use an XML editor that provides code completion if an XML schema is provided (e.g. the Eclipse XML editor).

Comment: @Ralf I have this route definition `<routes xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route id="testRoute">
        <from uri="file:data/"/> 
        <proesssor id="ScriptProcessor" class="com.mycompany.processor.ScriptProcessor"/> 
        <to uri="mock:result" />
    </route>
</routes>`. In the process method quoted above I print a simple message to the console. In that route next step is to read files in "data" directory, process them with some operations in the "process" method that now I use to print a simple message to the console.

Comment: The processor step in the route should be `<process ref="idOfProcessorBean" />`. Check out the [schema](http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring-2.14.1.xsd). You instantiate the processor as a regular spring bean and then reference it from the process step.

Comment: @Ralf Yes but the problem is that I use the `loadRoutesDefinition` and `addRouteDefinitions` methods of  Camel context and in this case I must write an xml file with only `<routes>` tag with `route` element inside. I can't use <bean> element outside. I try to use ` <process beanType="..."` but the route thows an exception. If I remove the bean type and let only to and from tag the route runs. But I need to call a process method of a Java class, I don't know the right way to connect this concepts.

Comment: I am sure you have your reasons... If I really had to do it that way I'd create a separate project, in that build the routes with the Java DSL, get the `RouteDefinition` from the `CamelContext` and marshal them using JAXB to an XML file. I.e. reverting the process of `DefaultCamelContext::loadRoutesDefinition(InputStream)`. Then you should be able to unmarshal the route again in your main project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in this way. I create a xml file with a route definition:

```
<route id="scriptProcessor">  
    <from uri="file:/C:/Users/milioli/Documents/NetBeansProjects/camel-rule-engines-processor/src/main/resources/samples/?noop=true"/>
    <bean beanType="com.mycompany.processor.ScriptProcessor" method="process"/> 
    <to uri="mock:result"/>  
    <onCompletion>
        <bean beanType="com.mycompany.processor.context.handler.ShutdownContextProcessor" method="process"/>
    </onCompletion>
</route>
```

Then in the process method I do operations that I need. The definition of the route in this way avoid me to load the definition using the method described [here](http://camel.apache.org/loading-routes-from-xml-files.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use processor that way:

```
<bean id="scriptProcessor" class="com.my.app.ScriptProcessor"/>

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route>
    <from uri="file:?noop=true"/>
    <process ref="scriptProcessor" />
    <to uri="mock:result"/>
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

Or use camel bean integration:

```
public class SomeBean {

    public void someMethod(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        //do something
    }
}
```

camel context:

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route>
    <from uri="file:?noop=true"/>
    <bean ref="someBean" method="someMethod"/>
    <to uri="mock:result"/>
  </route>
</camelContext>
```

For more details please see http://camel.apache.org/bean-language.html